# Select all columns with group by without selecting all them individually

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL:

```
declare @Users table (
  Id int not null primary key clustered (Id),
  [Name] nvarchar(255) not null
);

declare @Skills table (
  SkillId int not null primary key clustered (SkillId)
); 

declare @UserSkills table (
  UserId int not null, 
  SkillId int not null,
    primary key clustered (UserId, SkillId)
); 

insert into @Users
values (1, 'Jonh'), (2, 'Mary');

insert into @Skills
values (148), (149), (304), (305);

insert into @UserSkills
values (1, 149), (1, 305), (2, 148), (2, 149);

select u.Id, u.Name
from @Users as u
inner join @UserSkills as us
on u.Id = us.UserId
where us.SkillId in (149, 305)
group by u.Id, u.Name
having count(*) = 2
```

I am getting the User John as expected.

But in real code the User has 40 columns.

Is it possible to do the select / group by to use all columns without enumerating all individually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate *before* joining:

```
select u.*
from @Users u join
     (select us.UserId
      from @UserSkills us
      where us.SkillId in (149, 305)
      group by us.UserId
      having count(*) = 2
     ) us
     on u.Id = us.UserId
```